# How to schedule an automatic FTP download on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to schedule an automatic `FTP` download on Ubuntu? Currently I am using Filezilla to download my website's files manually. I want to schedule a task which will download my website's HTTPDOCS folder to my computer's onedrive/googledrive/TFS directory every night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your favorite text editor and put this in it...

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /directory/where/you/want/the/backup
wget -a /path/to/logfile/to/save -m ftp://user:pass@domain:port/path/to/dir
```

Save that file into a suitable location. My favorite is to make a dir named "bin" in my home directory. So that would be /home/username/bin

Save the file as backupweb.sh or something like that.
You will need to make it executable. If you're running in the GUI, you can simply right click on it, select the permissions tab, and then check all of the checkboxes for executable.
Alternatively, if you're using the shell, which you will have to in a moment, you can simply type
Code:

```
chmod +x /home/username/bin/backupweb.sh
```

Open a shell and type
Code:

```
crontab -e
```

It should ask you what editor you would like to use.
If you have one that you use and like, go for it, but if not, select vi, and proceed.
When vi is displayed, you will see a line at the top of the shell window showing
Code:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

Press the lower case "o" character on the keyboard.
You will see the cursor move to the next line, and it will say
-- INSERT -- at the bottom.
On that second line, type this...
Code:

```
5 0 * * * /home/username/bin/backupweb.sh
```

Then press the escape key on the keyboard, the -- INSERT -- will go away, and then press colon key, and then "wq" then press Enter.

That command will make it run on the 5th minute after midnight, every day (well.. night).

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1113569)